# i have a select2 and when i select multiple option and press backspace or unselect an option it unselects all options what should i do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2, backspace

i am using select 2 and problem is that it loads data accurately from ajax
but when i press backspace or deselect an element in select it deselects all selected options in select. and i want to deselect just only last element on backspace and deselect specific element if i click on x button which is enabled when allowClear property

how to over come it cannot found in select2 documentation

**here is the code of select 2 html**

```
<Select id="SubServicesId" class="form-control" name="SubServicesId" multiple="multiple"></Select>
```

**The Code for select2 is**

```
function ApplySelect2ServicesConfiguration(select) {
        //if ($(select).data('select2')) {
        //    $(select).select2('destroy');
        //}
        $(select).select2({
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            allowClear: true,
            quietMillis: 100,
            dropdownParent: $('#CheckInModal'),
            id: function (repo) { return repo.Id; },
            placeholder: {
                //  id: '-1', // the value of the option
                text: 'Select Service'
            },
            ajax: {
                url: "/Patients/GetSubServicesDDServerSide",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 300,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term, // search term
                        page: params.page || 1,
                        PageSize: window.PageSize,
                        'departmentId': null,
                        'IndividualPackageId': $('#IndividualPackageId').val(),
                        PatientId: window.PatientId,
                        // ServiceAppointmentId: $('#HiddenServiveAppointmentId').val(),
                        //  SubServiceIds: $('#HiddenSubServiceId').val(),
                        //  PaymentNo: $('#HiddenLabPaymentNo').val(),
                        PanelOrganizationId: $('#CheckInPanelOrganizationId').val(),
                        PanelPackageId: $('#CheckInOnPanelOrganizationPackageId').val(),
                        SubServiceCategoryId: $("#SubServiceCategoryId").val(),
                        SubDepartmentsId: $("#SubDepartmentsId").val(),
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {

                    params.page = params.page || 1;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                        data.items[i].text = data.items[i].Name.split(';')[0].split('--')[1]
                        data.items[i].id = data.items[i].Id
                    }
                    return {
                        results: data.items,
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * window.PageSize) < data.total_count
                        }
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            formatResult: function (element) {

                return element
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) {

                return markup;

            }, // let our custom formatter work

        });

        $(select).on('select2:select', function (e) {
            var data = e.params.data;
           
        });

     

        
        $(select).on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
            var unselectId = e.params.data.Id;
            var selectedIds = $(select).val();

            // Check if unselecting was initiated by a backspace key press
            if (e.params.originalEvent.inputType === 'delete' && selectedIds && selectedIds.length > 1) {
                // Manually remove the last selected item
                selectedIds.pop();
                $(select).val(selectedIds).trigger('change');
                e.preventDefault();
            }


        });

    }
```